# Convert Object Array to an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The trending Array is returning an Object Array and within this is an array of articles [ *articles: [{…}]*. ]

How do I convert this object array to a regular array & extract the articles array.

Object Array

```
*Object*
articles: [{…}]
status: "ok"
totalResults: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Code to fetch & set both arrays with articles.

```
 fetchNews() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(
        'url1',
      ),
      fetch(
        'url2',
      ),
    ])
      .then(([articles, trending]) => {
        return Promise.all([articles.json(), trending.json()]);
      })
      .then(([articles, trending]) => {
        return [articles, trending];
      })
      .then(([articles, trending]) => {
    

        this.setState({
          articles: articles,
          trending: trending.articles,
          refreshing: false,
        });
      });
  }
```

Data Structure of return Promise.all([articles.json(), trending.json()]);

```
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
map: {x-cache-remaining: "98", server: "cloudflare", nel: "{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}", content-encoding: "br", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", …}
[[Prototype]]: Object
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "default"
url: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=bitcoin&apiKey=fb54511458d44c91af1f35ce9d5a0f93"
_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}
_bodyInit: Blob {_data: {…}}
```

Trying to load trending.articles array into Carousel Component
& item comes back undefined.

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
          style={styles.bgColor}
          data={this.state.articles}
          renderItem={({item}) => <DataItem article={item} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.url}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.text}> Trending </Text>
              <Carousel
                layout={'default'}
                data={this.state.trending}
                renderItem={({item}) => <CarouselItem article={item} />}
                sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
                itemWidth={300}
              />
              <Text style={styles.text}> Blockchain News </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:180 Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

This error is located at:
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:620)
    in FlatList (at Home.js:74)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:51)
    in SafeAreaView (at Home.js:73)
    in Home (at SceneView.tsx:126)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:118)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:209)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screen.tsx:61)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Background.tsx:13)
    in Background (at Screen.tsx:56)
    in Screen (at BottomTabView.tsx:129)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:150)
    in Screen (at ScreenFallback.tsx:37)
    in MaybeScreen (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:189)
    in ScreenContainer (at ScreenFallback.tsx:28)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:93)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:38)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:92)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:112)
    in Unknown (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:111)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at TabNavigator/index.js:12)
    in TabNavigator (at RootNavigator.js:9)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:429)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at RootNavigator.js:8)
    in RootNavigator (at App.js:18)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `trending.articles`? Also, your `Object.keys` makes no sense and neither does a `console.log` as the only thing in a `.map` (`map` transforms and you are not returning anything, so `trendingArray` will never have any contents)

Comment: Yeah, I am looking at trending.articles. Trending returns the object containing the articles array. I need this article array in order to feed it into my data component, as data only takes an array @crashmstr

Comment: Problem solved :`trending.articles`?

Comment: @ikhvjs if i change it to trending.articles I get this error 'ExceptionsManager.js:180 Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN'

Comment: A suggestion: show us the data structure of result of`return Promise.all([articles.json(), trending.json()])`, then tell us what do you need from it.

Comment: @ikhvjs updated, will show the rest of code as well.

Comment: You should `console.log(articles, trending)` in the first `.then(([articles, trending]) ` instead...

Comment: Instead of console.log(), try console.table(). It will show the contents of arrays and nested objects.

Comment: @PeterB in which part, after the .json() or before that function?

Comment: @FrankBoccia, do this `.then(([articles, trending]) => {
        console.table(articles);
        console.table(trending);
      })`

Comment: @ikhvjs updated please look at question

Comment: What do you need to pass to setState() then?

Comment: I need to set the array, the state contains the empty array ```constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {articles: [], refreshing: true, trending: []};
    this.fetchNews = this.fetchNews.bind(this);
  }``` @ikhvjs

Comment: @ikhvjs I am trying to pass the articles array

Comment: `trending.articles` is correct then. you can `console.log(trending.articles)` to see that you get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236098/discussion-between-frank-boccia-and-ikhvjs).